# How would I go about redefining a .txt file into a valid jpeg?

Tags: text, jpeg, file-conversion

I know that renaming a file with a .txt extension to a .jpeg extension causes the file to open as a JPEG, but isn't really "valid" (meaning there is not an image shown).  Is there any way to change a .txt file into a .jpg file so that the computer displays a random image of ? x ? dimensions with colors and patterns based on the text within the .txt file without modifying it? I don't have any set pattern in mind to compare to.

I'm willing to field any questions in case I wasn't clear on what I'm asking for.

Comment: you mean like opening the file in notepad and creating a screenshot of it ?!?

Comment: Can I ask why you are trying to do this? Maybe knowing what you are trying to do would help in finding an answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

No.

A JPEG file is defined by a [very specific data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#The_JPEG_standard).  In general, the bytes of that data structure will take on all possible values from 0x0 to 0xff.  Text files typically do not contain all possible bytes.  Most text encodings contain at least some non-printable characters.

You could construct a valid JPEG using a hex editor and knowledge of the specification.  You could also use a text file as input to create the pixel data portion of the JPEG file, though you would have to construct the header by different means and ensure that an appropriate number of bytes are taken from the text file.

Answer (score 1):

No chances to do this like you want. 
First: jpeg uses binary encoding. 
Second: you need to fill many headers on file before write image.

Specifications and file organization:
JPEG data are byte streams, always storing 16-bit word values in big-endian format. JPEG data in general is stored as a stream of blocks, and each block is identified by a marker value.

The first two bytes of every JPEG stream are the Start Of Image (SOI) marker values FFh D8h. In a JFIF-compliant file there is a JFIF APP0 (Application) marker, immediately following the SOI, which consists of the marker code values FFh E0h and the characters JFIF in the marker data, as described in the next section. In addition to the JFIF marker segment, there may be one or more optional JFIF extension marker segments, followed by the actual image data.

More on: http://www.fileformat.info/format/jpeg/egff.htm

Answer (score 0):

What you are saying has no chance of happening. JPEG files have one of several file structures that share a common compressed data format.

A text file is going have lines of characters separated by , , or  sequences that will just screw up a compressed JPEG stream.

If you want to understand how JPEG works, you should get this book:
[http://www.amazon.com/Compressed-Image-File-Formats-JPEG/dp/0201604434/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1447202612&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201604434)